# Selenium webdriver not opening neither Chrome nor Firefox browser, I downloaded chromedriver, geckodriver in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Users\yhtiy\Documents\chromedriver_win32\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://instagram.com")`

And the output is:

> Process finished with exit code 0

I have tried to change the browser to Chrome and Firefox but the issue remains. I have checked that Selenium is installed.

Comment: `exit code 0` means everything is ok
What is the code you're running on?

Answer (score 0):

webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/yhtiy/Documents/chromedriver_win32/geckodriver.exe")

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running a script, when the script finishes, the process exits, nothing is wrong. If you want to see what's being obtained, save `driver.page_source` to a file or print it out.